# Getting the elapsed time of an asynchronous request

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to get the elapsed time during an asynchronous request, but I got a time which is totally different from the wireshark time.

That's really weird because i'm doing the same thing with a pool of synchronous requests and I got the wireshark time.

That is my code :

```
    public void getResponseAsync()
    {
        RequestState rs = new RequestState();
        rs.Request = this.webRequest;  //On ajoute la requete dans l'objet état pour pouvoir le récupérer dans la callback
        this.timerAsync.Restart();
        IAsyncResult ar = rs.Request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.ResponseCallback), rs);      // Appel asynchrone
    }

    public void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        RequestState rs = (RequestState)ar.AsyncState;  //Récupération de l'objet etat 
        HttpWebRequest req = rs.Request;                //Récupération de la requete web (object HttpWebRequest)
        try //Récupération de la réponse Web    
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar);
            this.timerAsync.Stop();
            this.timeAsync = this.timerAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            ...
            ...
         }
    }
```

The value of this.timeAsync is far away from the Wireshark value.

Did I make something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is only one call of getResponseAsync()?
Add a breakpoint on getResponseAsync to be certain.

Multiple calls of getResponseAsync will reset your timer.

Comment: For each request, I'm getting an async response but the timer is not restarted :  `for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        Response response = new Response(webRequest);
        response.getResponseAsync();}`

I got a higher value than the value which is expected.

Comment: Are you monitoring the callback that correspond to your getResponseAsync() call ? Because each getReponseAsync() will call your ResponseCallback. If you don't get the corresponding callback, you will get a wrong time value.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the problem with this snippet. I tried to put the start time in my RequestState object : `rs.start = DateTime.Now;` and in my ResponseCallback :
`RequestState rs = (RequestState)ar.AsyncState; 
  HttpWebRequest req = rs.Request;   
  DateTime start = rs.start;
  HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar); 
  this.timeAsync = Helpers.getDiffMs(start);`